# can i mark the attendance using cctvs cameras in android application

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition

i am building an Android app for a factory, cctv cameras are installed in factory, they want that when there employees come in the cameras detect the face of employee and automatically mark attendance of the employee in the inventory application

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's possible.

You would need multiple photos from all of the factory employees. And then write some facial recognition software using that data. Also, you would need a backend that connects to the mobile app, and reports the current status of present employees.

I would recommend learning OpenCV (Open Computer Vision).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind guide kian, could you please tell me that I'm using firebase for backend is it possible with it and is there any course or tutorial of this

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, you need a dataset of all the staff members with their faces clearly visible. You can train a face detection and identification model which will take care of recognising the faces. Then you gave a specific id or name, etc to those faces and apply a simple if condition,
This could help you in detecting the faces:
https://github.com/KA0335/Face-Recognition
This is my repo for face detection with credits given to the owner in the medium article which explains how it works.

Then after the face detection model is running smoothly you can just try to implement something like this pseudo code

```
if recognised_face has ID from the pool:

    Mark attendance for the person.
```

To do face recognition and identification.
If you are working on android I hope integrating python code with android would be an easy task for you!

Cheers